# Want both divs to be set to the max of their heights on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Clients are using a Content Management System to inject text into 2 divs that represent buttons. I want the buttons to be equal in height. The problem is:

- If I a set a height equal for both using `CSS`, then that only works if the client doesn't type in too much text.
- If I don't set a height using `CSS`, then that only works if the client types in the same number of lines of text into both.

So I think JQuery will come to the rescue on this one. Can you help me figure out which functions to use?

An outline of the issue is:

```
<div id="button1">
    <p>Here's some text that the client will control.</p>
</div>
<div id="button2">
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     /* Here will go some JS to make button1 and button2 the height of whichever one is taller when the page has loaded the client's text that the CMS injected */
</script>
```

Comment: As a jQuery option, have a look at: http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No JQuery... Make them `display: table-cell` elements, and they'll match each other's height automatically...

```css
#button1, #button2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="button1">
    <p>Here's some text that the client will control.</p>
</div>
<div id="button2">
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control Here's some more text that the client will control Here's some more text that the client will control Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Another CSS option would be Flexbox layout (However it seems to be a hammer to crack nuts! in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery solution

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/hyo0zsfj/

HTML

```
<div class="button" id="button1">
    <p>Here's some text that the client will control.</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="button2">
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
</div>
<div class="button" id="button3">
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
    <p>Here's some more text that the client will control</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttons = $('.button'),
        btnsLgth = buttons.length,
        biggerHeight = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < btnsLgth; i++){
        var btnHeight = buttons.eq(i).height();
        if(btnHeight > biggerHeight) biggerHeight = btnHeight;
    }
    buttons.height(biggerHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can for example take the max  height and apply it to both ,below a simple jquery solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// wait until the document is ready 
// 1 : grab the default height of the two divs 
var button1Height = $('#button1').css('height'); // example 50px
var button2Height = $('#button2').css('height'); // example 60px

// 2: we have to remove the suffix px and we can achieve this by using replace method
button1Height = button1Height.replace('px',''); // now the value is 50
button2Height = button2Height.replace('px',''); // now the value is 60

//3: now choose the max between the two heights and make it the height of both 

if(button1Height >= button2Height){
 $('#button2').css('height',button1Height+'px');

}else{
 $('#button1').css('height',button2Height+'px');
}

// now #button1 and #button2 should have the same height
button1NewHeight =  $('#button1').css('height'); 
button2NewHeight =  $('#button2').css('height'); 

// you should get button1NewHeiht == button2NewHeight

});
```